# React HOC with Context - should not use <Route render> and <Route children> in the same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

So I am running into the infamous React Router v4 warning:

**`Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored`**

This happens after wrapping my component, which itself renders a `<Route />` inside my HOC which provides my React context.

This all looks a bit like this:

`App.js`:

```
<myContextProvider>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <myLayout path="/foo" Component={someComponent}>
      ...
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</myContextProvider>
```

my `stores.js` file includes the following:

```
export const withMainStore = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    return (
      <MainConsumer>
        {store => (
          <Component {...store} {...props} />
        )}
      </MainConsumer>
    )
  }
}
```

`myLayout.js`:

```
class myLayout extends React.Component {
  const { Component, ...rest } = this.props;
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        <Component {...rest} {...props} />
      )}/>
    )
  }
}

export default withMainStore(myLayout)
```

I hope my whole situation here is somewhat clear. can someone explain to me why the warning occurs? **At NO point in my whole app, I have something like: `<Route>...</Route>` - I am always using `<Route {...rest} render={(props) => ( ... )} />`!**

So I got no idea why this is happening. I has to have something todo with my `withMainStore` HOC, because when I remove it the error is gone. but still I do not understand why this causes the error.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `component` property in your redux store?

Comment: This isn't a redux store, but my own "store" made with the context api. and yes, some props might sometimes contain a `component` prop.